# How can i find the row which has the most 0 values in an int 2D array?

Tags: java

How can i find the row which has the most 0 values in an int 2D array?

Example:

```
int[][] arr = new int[4][5]; 
arr[0][0] = 1;
arr[0][1] = 2;
arr[0][2] = 3;
arr[0][3] = 4;

arr[1][0] = 29;
arr[1][1] = 28;
arr[1][2] = 27;

arr[2][0] = 3;
arr[2][1] = 33;

arr[3][0] = 41;
arr[3][1] = 42;
arr[3][2] = 43;
arr[3][3] = 43;
```

The answer is should be Row index 2

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed the code block, since it made your post easier to read.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem.
What did you try? Can you show us some code?
Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. I would use `stream`s for that job:

```
    int[][] arr = new int[4][5]; 
    arr[0][0] = 1;
    arr[0][1] = 2;
    arr[0][2] = 3;
    arr[0][3] = 4;
    
    arr[1][0] = 29;
    arr[1][1] = 28;
    arr[1][2] = 27;
    
    arr[2][0] = 3;
    arr[2][1] = 33;

    arr[3][0] = 41;
    arr[3][1] = 42;
    arr[3][2] = 43;
    arr[3][3] = 43;
    
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
            .map(row -> Map.entry(row, Arrays.stream(arr[row]).filter(i -> i != 0).count()))
            .min(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .ifPresent(row -> System.out.println("Row: " + row));
```

**Output**

```
Row: 2
```

**Update**

If you want to use a `for loop` you can do:

```
    int row = -1;
    int maxZeros = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int zeros = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                zeros++;
            }
        }
        if (zeros > maxZeros) {
            maxZeros = zeros;
            row = i;
        }
    }
    
    if (row > -1) {
        System.out.println("Row: " + row);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Row: 2
```

Comment: Thanks Obeo for your Answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it solved your issue, please accept the answer ;)

Comment: Is there easier methode?, because i am beginner. i want understand how the methode works

Comment: Easier is subjective, but a for loop can do the job in a very simple way.

Comment: Can you solve it with for loop, please?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer with that alternative.